# Using Google feed api java

Tags: java, google-feed-api

I'm trying to fetch some data using Google feed api. But line = reader.readLine() is always null.

```
URL url = new URL("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find?" +
                    "v=1.0&q=Official%20Google%20Blog");
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            String line;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             builder.append(line);
            }

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
```

Comment: How you know its null, try to print `line` inside your while loop and check what actually is coming

Comment: I  checked with a debugger.

Comment: I tried your code and i am able to get the data without any modification. I recommend you put a print statement in your while loop and check.

Comment: You were right. But there is another problem.The code's is getting not entire data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    URL url = new URL("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find?" +
            "v=1.0&q=Official%20Google%20Blog");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

    ByteArrayOutputStream content = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    int len = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while ((len = is.read(buffer)) >= 0)
    {
        content.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    byte[] finalContent = content.toByteArray();
    String str = new String(finalContent, "UTF8");
    System.out.print(str);
```

Or other way is you can read the `content-length` header and read that till you get that much data.

Comment: I found out that logcat didn't print entire data. Thanks anyway.